# BIOS firmware issues?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, bios, thinkpad, firmware

my laptop is a Lenovo ThinkPad e440, I bout it "brand new" from a friend of mine. the laptop workes just fine but after EXACTLY 30 minutes the laptop just shuts off (as if I removed the battery NOT turning off) without any fan or heat problems, I went to a technician and after he examined it for a couple of days he told me its a "BIOS firmware problem" he told me that the firmware on the BIOS is not the right one for this device, I found online an identical firmware from a trusted source but requires money to get, so my only question, does the problem makes sense or not? and if anyone knows where can I get the firmware for free or at least for a good price?

Comment: BIOS is made available by the PC manufacturer and should never be downloaded from a 3rd party site unless there are solid reasons to 100% trust the 3rd party.  It could be a multitude of things, but I'd first verify there's not a Windows task shutting it down after 30min, then boot into the hardware diagnostics and run a basic and extended test _(will take several hours)_.

Comment: This PC has no BIOS, but has UEFI firmware, and it is clearly available from the manufacturer here: https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-edge-laptops/thinkpad-edge-e440/downloads/ds037207

Comment: That said... This sounds like a "technician" who didn't want to deal with the issue. If the UEFI firmware was incorrect, the device would not shutdown after 30 minutes it would  be immediately. Boot up a Linux distro on USB and see if it shuts down... this really sounds like an OS issue, not a hardware or firmware issue. \

Comment: You can get the firmware from Lenovo for free.  The firmware that is being sold for a fee is a scam

Comment: @acejavelin I already tried updating the BIOS but that made no difference.

Comment: @Ramhound the firmware available at Lenovo is only to update not to install a whole new one

Comment: @acejavelin before I have windows 10 on the device it came with windows 7 and it faced the exact same problem.

Comment: If it is *exactly* 30 minutes every time then your "friend" might have played a joke on you and put a timed shutdown command to run on startup. Doing a *clean* install would remove that as a source of problems.

Comment: it may not be BIOS causing this. We service hundreds of Lenovo machines and they will not accept the wrong BIOS.  As noted above try updating BIOS from the Lenovo Support page for that model. That is how I do it. Other causes:  Root Kit virus (run TDSSKiller from Kaspersky).  Memory going bad after heating up. If 2 modules exists, try just one and then the other. Wait more than 30 minutes each time

Comment: How do you know you have no heat problems? If there is any power management feature in the BIOS, disable it, or reset the BIOS. Does this happen when booting in Safe Mode?

Comment: @harrymc ik because there is no pressure being provided to the laptop (it shuts off even when im on the desktop and nothing is oppend) and there is just no heat at all coming from the machine and the fan is quiet. and im only using it in safe mode.

Comment: Did you have a look into the BIOS, or tried to reset it?

Comment: Have you run a Linux LiveDVD or USB to see if the problem still occurs there?

Comment: Say what you will, but this is NOT a UEFI firmware issue... it could be a heat issue, or other hardware issue, but my money would be on something in the OS. Do a CLEAN install (not a "reset") or try a different OS from USB like Linux.